# Validation message was not showing after upgrading the laravel version

Tags: php, laravel

I just upgrade my laravel version from 5.4 to 6.0. After upgrading, i noticed that everything is working fine but validation messages are not showing. I search a lot but did not get any solution. Please smoone help me to solve this. This is my code for store controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $shifts = Shift::whereTime('in_time','=', $request->in_time)
            ->whereTime('out_time','=', $request->out_time)
            ->where('branch_id',$request->branch)->pluck('name');
        $rules = [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('shifts','name')->where(function ($query) use ($shifts){
                    return $query->whereIn('name', $shifts);
                }),
            ],
            'in_time' => 'required',
            'out_time' => 'required',
            'checking_time' => 'required|after_or_equal:in_time|before:out_time',
            'status' => 'required',
            'branch' => 'required',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        // store
        $shift = new Shift();
        $shift->name = $request->name;
        $shift->branch_id = $request->branch;
        $shift->display_name = $request->display_name;
        $shift->in_time = database_formatted_time($request->in_time);
        $shift->out_time = database_formatted_time($request->out_time);
        $shift->last_check_in_time = database_formatted_time($request->checking_time);
        $shift->status = $request->status;
        $shift->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        if ($shift->save()) {
            if ($request->default_shift)
            {
                $d_shift = new DefaultShift();
                $d_shift->shift_id = $shift->id;
                $d_shift->save();
            }
            return ['type' => 'success', 'title' => 'Success!', 'autoDataLoad' => route('load.shift'), 'message' => 'Shift Has been created Successfully'];
        }

        return ['type' => 'error', 'title' => 'Failed!', 'message' => 'Something wents wrong'];
    }
```

And in view i use it like these

```
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
```

Comment: Could you paste your code ?

Comment: yes i edit the post, please check

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding Laravel [Validation Docs v6.x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation), i can't find any mach with
>   `$this->validate($request, $rules);`

Instead make use of

```
$request->validate([
                //...
                'in_time' => 'required',
                'out_time' => 'required',
                'checking_time' => 'required|after_or_equal:in_time|before:out_time',
                'status' => 'required',
                'branch' => 'required',
                //...
]);
```

> You may also use the `@error` Blade directive to quickly check if
>   validation error messages exist for a given attribute.

```
@error('name')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: i think the problem is different

Comment: according to you now i changed my code to this
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'in_time' => 'required',
            'out_time' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'branch' => 'required',

        ]);

Comment: You can dd('Validation pass'); just before this line $shift = new Shift(); to get sure your validation pass or not

Comment: i checked in network it gives me all the messages but dosnot show in form

Comment: You may use the @error Blade directive to quickly check if validation error messages exist for a given attribute.



Check doc https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: @TanvirAhmed is it smth related to SESSION_DRIVER ??

Comment: i am not sure about but i install a new laravel application and then i change my middleware and kernel folder and after that i did config:cache